# reek complaints for DuplicateMethodCall format.json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reek

I have this code reek complains for  DuplicateMethodCall (calls format.json twice)

```
if object_error.blank?
  format.json { render json: order }
else
  format.json { render json: object_error, status: :unprocessable_entity }
end
```

What is the best way to do it in rails? or is this false positive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no need in refactoring in this particular case.

This, and other variations occurs errors too:

```
format.json { render(object_error.blank? ? (json: order) : (json: object_error, status: :unprocessable_entity) }
```

And it's less readable.